# How to call implicitly constructor of value wrapped in shared_ptr which is placed in std::map collection

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

I'm working with code generator where I can't obtain directly classname of the value which is wrapped in `shared_ptr` and placed in `std::map`.

I came to a situation where I need to create new map object but without access to classname I can't perform a valid object constructor call. I tried with the map operator at[], which calls the value constructor, but it calls `shared_ptr<T>` constructor and the object inside stays uninitialized.

Here the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A"; }
    int getMember() const { return m_member; }
private:
    int m_member = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, A> mapIntToA;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>> mapIntToAptr;

    mapIntToA[1]; // runs A constructor
    std::cout << mapIntToA[1].getMember();
    
    mapIntToAptr[1]; // runs shared_ptr constructor
    // cant call methods of uninitalized object
    // std::cout << mapIntToAptr[1]->getMember();
    
    // this init works, but I can't use classname 'A' in my code generator
    // mapIntToAptr[1] = std::make_shared<A>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All std types (and many types of other libraries) that have template arguments provide an alias that allows to retrieve the type of the template argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the member types of `std::map` and `std::shared_ptr` to get the type of the element.

Something like

```
using type = typename std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>>::mapped_type::element_type;
mapIntToAptr[1] = std::make_shared<type>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mapIntToAptr.emplace(1, ::std::make_shared<decltype(mapIntToAptr)::mapped_type::element_type>());
```

Note that use of `emplace` prevents a situation when map is left with nullptr value when  `make_shared` throws.

Answer (score 2):

`operator[]` of `std::map` default constructs absent value.

So, you might wrap `std::shared_ptr` into a class which constructs you inner class as expected, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct shared_ptr_wrapper
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> data = std::make_shared<T>();

    operator const std::shared_ptr<T>& () const {return data;}
    operator std::shared_ptr<T>& () {return data;}

    const std::shared_ptr<T>& operator ->() const { return data; }
    std::shared_ptr<T>& operator ->() {return data;}

    const T& operator *() const { return *data; }
    T& operator *() {return *data;}
};
```

then

```
std::map<int, shared_ptr_wrapper<A>> mapIntToAptr;

mapIntToAptr[1]; // runs shared_ptr constructor
std::cout << mapIntToAptr[1]->getMember(); // Ok
```